# JQuery remove image class a if in div with class b

Tags: jquery

Im new to JQuery. I'm trying to figure out how to use it to remove an image class only if that image is in a div with a different specific class. Here's what i have so far. Any help would be very much appreciated. thanks.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("class.bundled_product_images").find("img").removeClass("image zoom");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bundled_product_images">
  <figure class="bundled_product_image woocommerce-product-gallery__image">
    <img src="x" class="image zoom" class="another class">
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: you can't have two class attributes. You can have all four space separated like this `image zoom another class`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the word `class` in `$("class.bundled_product_images")`:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".bundled_product_images").find("img").removeClass("image zoom");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bundled_product_images">
  <figure class="bundled_product_image woocommerce-product-gallery__image">
    <img src="x" class="image zoom another class">
  </figure>
</div>
```

And as Neville noted in the comments, you can't have two `class` definitions in any one element, but you can combine them.

Comment: It was me, I upvoted, then removed my upvote due to my jsPerf test case I posted in an answer below. Your answer is acceptable, and certainly works, but it appears to execute slower than using `hasClass()`. Nothing against your answer, the only reason I even posted one was due to the jsPerf tests.

Comment: @AndyWarren well, thanks for the comment, although I don't know if my answer warranted a downvote. As the tooltip for downvotes says, "This answer is not useful" I don't know if I agree. Plus, why just downvote me?

Comment: I didn't realize it had negative impact, I just assumed it was reversing my upvote.

Comment: I tested it. If you keep running the tests the "fastest" alternates between both codes. So neither can be shown as faster. Of course mostly more code is faster. By that logic we can just use raw js. It is simply up to the coders to decide performance vs code size.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use

```
$(".bundled_product_images img").removeClass("image zoom");
```

You don't need class. The dot represents a class, no symbol before the word represents an element (img in this case) and space before `img` represents the `img` is inside the element with a bundled_product_images class. As per your title, if you want to explicitly look for a DIV element with the class, use:

```
$("div.bundled_product_images img").removeClass("image zoom");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this with jQuery. @j08691 and @Neville-Nazerane both posted possible solutions that do work, but it appears using jQuery `hasClass()` actually executes faster. Here is a test that shows the three current answers, including this one with `hasClass()`: https://jsperf.com/jquery-remove-class-has-class-aw Just go to that link and click "Run test".

Here's a `hasClass()` example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if (('*').hasClass('bundled_product_images')) {
        jQuery(this).find("img").removeClass("image zoom");
    }
});
```

I will say, I'm somewhat surprised by the jsPerf results.

Comment: I kept running the tests. The fastest in fact alters between your and @j08691's codes.

Comment: I must have ran it 15 times because I simply couldn't believe the `hasClass()` was the fastest, and that is the only one I could get to win in either Chrome or Firefox.